# Cannot add Facebook account

Tags: facebook, accounts

I am trying to add a Facebook account in my account settings, but as I do so I am sent back to the settings menu. I simply cannot add a Facebook account.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried just logging into the Facebook app on your phone? Does this work?  Do you then see a Facebook setting under the Accounts part of Settings?

Comment: I can log into Facebook with the Facebook App and the Facebook Messenger App. In Settings > Accounts, no Facebook is listed. If I select "Add Account" then I see a Facebook option. If I select that option, I return to the Settings.

Comment: Having installed and logged into Facebook, is it working? Can you read people's posts, reply, use the messenger etc?  It seems that all the settings you need are available from within the app itself.  Is there some specific functionality you believe you need to add a facebook account to get working?  (When I poke around there, in the phone's settings, rather than Facebook's, it seems to want me to allow single sign on for some S3 group or other, which I don't want anyway!)

Comment: The problem lay not with the Facebook App itself, which functions without problem. It is rather with adding a Facebook account in the Android Settings, so I may retrieve my Facebook contacts in my address book. Also, other apps are unable to log in to Facebook (eg. Contact +).